# Is it possible for 2 JQuery-ajax working at the same time for the same page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to run 2 JQuery-ajax at the same time, but it's seem always done the 1st JQuery-ajax before the 2nd JQuery-ajax. Just wandering, is it possible for 2 JQuery-ajax working at the same time for the same page?

For example:

I created a page which will allows the user to insert a batch of records into the database, and at the same page it have a table to display all data inside the database.

I have use setInterval to call a function and to retrive the data with JQuery-ajax every 5 sec. The retrived data than will display on the screen, which means those data will be update every 5 sec on the screen.

When I pressed a process button in the same page to insert batch of records into the database with JQuery-ajax (it may take 2 mins to finish the process). At this point, the screen will only able to update the display data on the screen after the insert process is completed even those I had set setInterval to retrive the data with JQuery-ajax every 5 sec.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? or It's any way that I can submit 2 JQuery-ajax and do thier task at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The A in Ajax stands for Asynchronous. So really, almost by definition you should be able to have multiple requests running simultaneously. [(LogicFlux)](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=163826)

[Here's a blog](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=173) post that goes into some discussion on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have a [two http connections per server limitation](http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue), this can be changed in firefox in the about:config, and in ie in windows registry (not sure where)

In your case, maybe the db server is blocking the reading request because there a writing transaction going on that locks the table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with JavaScript. I had two instances of async $.ajax() run ot once but first one had on "success: window.location = "www.google.pl";

If first instance finished, it tried to redirect to new location. But second instance was still working.

That was the reason of this error.